# Mutable reference inside future from outer function

Tags: rust

It is possible to modify a function argument in-place with the following code snippet:

```rust
let mut foo = 1;
let mut fun: Box<dyn FnMut(&mut i32) -> _> = Box::new(|f| {
    *f += 1;
});
fun(&mut foo);
assert_eq!(foo, 2);
```

However, I have the case where the function `fun` needs to return a future which modifies the argument once the future gets awaited. Basically I have the following scenario:

```rust
let mut foo = 1;
assert_eq!(foo, 1);
let mut fun: Box<dyn FnMut(&mut i32) -> _> = Box::new(|f| {
    async move {
        *f += 1;
    }
});
fun(&mut foo).await;
assert_eq!(foo, 2);
```

[rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=%0A%23%5Btokio%3A%3Amain%5D%0Aasync%20fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20foo%20%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!(foo%2C%201)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20fun%3A%20Box%3Cdyn%20FnMut(%26mut%20i32)%20-%3E%20_%3E%20%3D%20Box%3A%3Anew(%7Cf%7C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20async%20move%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*f%20%2B%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fun(%26mut%20foo)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20assert_eq!(foo%2C%202)%3B%0A%7D%0A)

But this gives the compile error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
6 |       let mut fun: Box<dyn FnMut(&mut i32) -> _> = Box::new(|f| {
  |                                                              -- return type of closure `impl Future<Output = ()>` contains a lifetime `'2`
  |                                                              |
  |                                                              has type `&'1 mut i32`
7 | /         async move {
8 | |             *f += 1;
9 | |         }
  | |_________^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`

error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I am not sure how to annotate lifetimes in my code snippet above. I have tried `Box<dyn FnMut(&'static mut i32) -> _>`, but this gives that `foo` does not live long enough.

Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: This is a complicated issue. I don't have time to deep dive now, but boxing the future works: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3bc6e30dda2d0c0eaa9cf4dcf142efde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply change the value from (potentially) another thread without packing it with some synchronization primitive.

Instead, you can pack it with `Arc` and `Mutex` and deal with it like a multithreading program:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let foo = Arc::new(Mutex::new(1));
    assert_eq!(*foo.lock().unwrap(), 1);
    let mut fun: Box<dyn FnMut(Arc<Mutex<i32>>) -> _> = Box::new(|f| {
        async move {
            let mut counter = f.lock().unwrap();
            *counter += 1;
        }
    });
    fun(Arc::clone(&foo)).await;
    assert_eq!(*foo.lock().unwrap(), 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid using synchronization primitive since I will not be using multi-threaded future execution.

Comment: This is plain wrong. Multithreading is not related, this is an issue stemming from a lacking corner in Rust's type system.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman So this solution is good, but the explanation is not correct?

Comment: @complikator Yes. What solves here is the `Arc`, the `Mutex` is just an artifact (and BTW, prefer atomics where possible).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman
but to do this I need to call `Arc::get_mut(&mut f)` which will fail, because there are other arc to given value

Comment: @complikator You need the `Mutex`, but only because `Arc` is read only.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman So do you see a better solution to this problem? Because I understood that you said that mine is overkill

Comment: @complikator I didn't say that, I only said that your explanation is wrong. And I do have at least one other solution to the problem, to box the future.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman ok, so can you edit my answer? And thank you for comments

Comment: @complikator You can edit it yourself if you want. I am not editing answers that are not mine to change their meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I tried moving the function `fun` to a generic function definition instead of boxing it, which seems to work:

```rust
fn fun<'a>(f: &'a mut i32) -> impl futures::Future<Output = ()> + 'a {
    async move {
        *f += 1;
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut foo = 1;
    assert_eq!(foo, 1);
    fun(&mut foo).await;
    assert_eq!(foo, 2);
}
```

This seems to work since I can annotate the lifetimes in this setup. This solution requires that I await it immediately, since the `&mut i32` can only exist in one place at once. I.e. the following wouldn't work:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut foo = 1;
    assert_eq!(foo, 1);
    let fut = fun(&mut foo);
    assert_eq!(foo, 1);
    fut.await;
    assert_eq!(foo, 2);
}
```

Comment: I think that passing future explicitly without Boxing can be inefficient because the StateMachine that is under the Future implementation needs to be copied between stack

Comment: @complikator (a) [The state machine for this future is only 16 bytes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c80de20a6adaf9e8520287f7e73d6b61). (b) Boxing should be less efficient than memcpy. (c) This is a general advice about futures, not related to this question.